# Python rounding numbers inaccurate

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I have these two values that needed to round to two decimal spaces

```
n = 59.9250
n1 = 459.4250

print(round(n, 2))
print(round(n1, 2))
```

output

```
59.92
459.43
```

can someone explain why and there is a way to round both the same way I'm using python version 3.6.8

Comment: Note: when you say "inaccurate" or "wrong" you should provide also what are your expectations. There is no agreed way to round decimal points. Really: each one of the three common ways fails on some common cases (and that just using positive values). Different fields in mathematics and science will use different convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python uses IEEE-754 double precision numbers for the built-in floating point objects, meaning that the vast majority of numbers cannot be represented exactly. You can test this experimentally by creating a variable just below and above the limit:

```py
>>> n3 = 1e308 ; n3
1e+308
>>> n3 = 1e309 ; n3
inf
```

But, since CPython is open source, you can also verify this by looking at the code which handles floating point objects. In CPython, it can be found in [`Objects/floatobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/floatobject.c) and you'll see that code peppered with C `double` variables to hold the values.

---

So, if you type those two numbers into a conversion site such as [this binary converter](https://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html), you will see they convert into the closest matches as follows:

```
                   |
 59.925       59.92499999.....something
459.925      459.42500000..1..something
                   |
```

You can see there that, following the rule "next digit of `0..4` rounds down, while `5..9` rounds up", the first one will round *down* to `59.92` because the next digit is `4` (keeping in mind that no special "half-way" behaviour comes into play here because neither is exactly half-way).

For the same reason, the second one will round *up* to `459.93` because its next digit is `5`.

The [Python documentation for `round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) actually calls out this possibility:

> Note: The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

---

If you *really* want to avoid this issue, you should be skipping the use of the built-in floating point objects with all their foibles, and instead opt for using the `Decimal` class.

You can then manipulate numbers in a great many ways with that while avoiding loss of precision. For example, the following transcript:

- creates the *exact* value (not some closest floating point match);
- changes the context so that it rounds half values away from zero (*not* up towards infinity as you may think from the `ROUND_HALF_UP` specifier) rather than using banker's rounding; then
- rounds the value to two decimal places

```py
>>> d = decimal.Decimal("59.925")
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> round(d, 2)
Decimal('59.93')
```

Comment: I've removed the answer cause your answer is better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In python there is a problem storing decimal numbers, python stores an aproximation of the number. You can see the real stored number using the decimal library.

```
from decimal import Decimal

num = 59.925

print(Decimal(num))
```

To solve this isue you can just use the fraction library doc: [fraction library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) or you can just add a really small number to get a good round result to improve the precision of the decimal number. For example:

```
precision = 6
correction = 10**(-precision)

num = 59.0250
print(round(num+correction, 2)
```

In this case you will have a precision of 6 decimal digits in your float numbers. You can check the real stored number using the Decimal library again.

Comment: I'd probably prefer to use the built-in rounding context for `Decimal` than some possibly dodgy corrective factor :-) But the use of `Decimal` is good, getting away from the foibles of floating point, so kudos there.

Answer (score 0):

### Round is accurate the problem is in floating numbers.

the thing is, this function `round()` useses something called
`banker's rounding` which means

"If the number to be rounded is exactly halfway between two possible rounded values, it is rounded to the nearest even number." for example.
2.5 will be 2 because 2 is even
3.5 will be 4 because 4 is even

In your case, when rounding `n = 59.9250` to two decimal places, it is exactly halfway between `59.92` and `59.93`. Since `59.92` is an even number, the round() function rounds down to the nearest even number, resulting in `59.92`. which is correct.

let's see now why this not true for `459.4250` since it should be `459.42` following same rule.

The reason you're getting `459.43` instead of `459.42` is due to a limitation in the floating-point representation of numbers in Python and all the programming language to be specific.

Floating-point numbers are represented in binary, and when working with decimal numbers, there can be small precision errors due to the inherent limitations of binary representation.

there is very famous example on this called `floating point problem` and why we shouldn't use floating numbers in  money calculation.

to avoid this floating point problem most language implemented `decimal`. you can use it to avoid this problem.

```
from decimal import Decimal

n1 = Decimal('459.4250')

rounded_n1 = round(n1,2)

print(rounded_n1)
```

**output: is `459.42` as you want it**

Comment: Decial library in this case doesn't solve the issue with the number 59.9250 the round result is still returning 59.92 insted of 59.93 using round(Decimal('59.9250'),2). You need a decimal.getcontext() change in the rounding variable

Comment: And even with round half up, the `float` value of `59.925` would still got to `59.92`, because it's *actually* `59.924999...`.

Comment: @paxdiablo he wanted both values to have same round `459.43` is now `459.42` and this what he wants i think.
and for `59.925` is expected to be `59.92` with round half also , `my answer is about using decmial number instead of floating numbers`

Comment: @kithuto i don't think we need getcontext() since decimal rounding will work fine with round half method which `round()` uses and you can see this from code it gives him what he wants

Comment: Good point, rereading the questions confirms that OP just wanted the same behaviour but without specifying what the behaviour should be :-) They should probably state more clearly what they expect to see. Hence this answer is as valid as mine but it remains to be seen what the think when they compare `4.425 -> 4.42`and `4.435 -> 4.44`.